# Getting SQL to use the correct index

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization, indexing, query-optimization

I have a table with two indexes, one of which is the faster covering index for a certain query. However, mySQL (5.1) is not choosing the correct index. I have looked at the explain for this query and done some speed tests and it makes a big difference if you force the key.

Is there any way of examining how it picks the index and what criteria it is basing this on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will use the index you need (in case it's usable):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table FORCE INDEX (myindex)
```

`MySQL` collects and uses table statistics to estimate the cardinality of the indexes.

It keeps it in `information_schema.statistics`.

Of two indexes that may be applied for filtering, `MySQL` chooses the one with greater cardinality.

If there are two indexes with big cardinality, it can choose `INDEX MERGE` over both of them.

In one index can serve `WHERE` condition and another one can serve `ORDER BY`, `MySQL` seems to prefer the first one

In the latter case, however, it's better to create a composite index over both columns, which can serve both clauses.